# Pagination error in controller page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am unable to paginate properly in my controller page for my view function. Please assist. The following code below is for my controller page. Have I assigned all the values properly in the paginate?

```
 function view() {
    $user_id = $this->layout = 'mainLayout';
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if (!empty($user_id)) {
        $userInfo = $this->User->getUserInfo($user_id);

    $friends_list = $this->Connection->getFriendsId($user_id);

    //getting the friends information by just passing the id of the user
    $all_friends_info = Classregistry::init('User')->getUserInfoList($user_id, $friends_list);

    $this->set(compact('all_friends_info','userInfo'));

    }

  $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('User.id' =>$all_friends_info),
                            'limit' => 10);
  $data = $this->paginate('friends_list');
  $this->set('friends_list',$data );
  $this->set('data', $this->paginate('User', $all_friends_info));
}
```

In my view page I have the necessary display codes:

```
 <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
        'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% users out of %count% total connections', true)
    ));
    ?>  </p>

<div class="paging">
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
    |   <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
    |
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats up with overwriting user_id in line 2,3? And what errors do you get if you put debug on 2? Oh and: $data = $this->paginate(); can be empty... How did you end up with this code?

Comment: @HansWassink is correct in asking why you are assigning $user_id in lines 2 and 3.  Also, have you set the $paginate variable in the controller?  Could you also clarify what is happening?  You state that it's not paginating properly, but what exactly do you mean?  Are you not getting any data from the controller or are the pagination links not working?  Please be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I see a LOT of mistakes, and maybe one of them is the problem :S (you never said what really the problem is, just not paging correctly is to big....

1) as Hans wassink said: this `$user_id = $this->layout = 'mainLayout';`should be `$this->layout = 'mainLayout';`

2) You are doing one of two things wrong

2.a) `$all_friends_info = Classregistry::init('User')->getUserInfoList($user_id, $friends_list);` Why you call classregistry::init if you have it in $this->User

2.b) if you don't have the user model loaded then why you use `$userInfo = $this->User->getUserInfo($user_id);`

3) now to the real problem the paginate part

```
  $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('User.id' =>$all_friends_info),
                            'limit' => 10);
  $data = $this->paginate('friends_list');
  $this->set('friends_list',$data );
  $this->set('data', $this->paginate('User', $all_friends_info));
```

Here you are doing TWO paginates!!! this WILL mess up your paginates, at least the part of $this->Paginator... in this case it should get the last one. Doing two paginates is a little more complex than it seems. You may need to pass the page as named param and parse it since it won't recognize wich page is which....

[here is a page](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-have-multiple-paginated-widgets-on-the-same-page-with-cakephp:48ad241e-b018-4532-a748-0ec74834cda3) of how to do this

Hope this helps you, if i miss something just comment ;)